# How does `should` work after a `filter` in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 6.8. I have one document in my index as shown below:

```
$ curl "http://localhost:9200/users/_search"|jq
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "users",
        "_type": "1",
        "_id": "WzLeNG4BVtGh82ZM-BBl",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "joey",
          "description": "xpxpxp all xpxpxp"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I use below query it does return me the document.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "name": "joey"
                }   
            },
            "should": [
                {
                    "constant_score": {
                        "filter": {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "description": "xpxpxp dd All xpxpxp"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But it returns nothing if I use below query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "constant_score": {
                        "filter": {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "description": "xpxpxp dd All xpxpxp"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The different between these two queries requests is that the first one has a `filter` before `should`. I wonder why this changes the `should` behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should clause matches nothing since the `match_phrase` on the `description` field cannot match `xpxpxp dd All xpxpxp` since that field contains `xpxpxp all xpxpxp`

The first query returns the document because the `name` field matches `joey`.

Comment: Does this mean the logic is `or` with the two condition `filter` and `should`?

Comment: What I meant is that your should clause is wrong and hence cannot match anything. But yes, anything in `should` is considered OR.